# Datatable Ajax receive data with success/complete (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm trying to receive data on the client-side from the controller using ajax, but what is happened is
I received data and it shows in the table when I using **`complete function`** in ajax but when I use  **`success function`** the data did not show in the table. From what I know the success function start earlier than the complete function, I want to use success to show some alert, If I put success alert in **`complete function`** it will display even when  **`error function`** is executed.

when I put both functions complete to return data and success to show the alert the data did not show in the table

#### Ajax

```
//...

  $('#inputForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        $("#submit").addClass("double loading");
        $("#tableLabel").show();
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#allInfoTable").DataTable({
           // processing: true,
           // serverSide: true,
            destroy: true,
            responsive: true,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            ordering: true,
            dom: 'QlBfrtip',
            buttons: ['colvis', 'excel', 'csv', 'print', 'copy', { extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                                                   title: 'Revenue Report',
                                                                   orientation: 'landscape',
                                                                   pageSize: 'A4',//A0 is the largest A5 smallest(A0,A1,A2,A3,legal,A4,A5,letter))
                                                                   select: {style: 'multi'},
                                                                   exportOptions: {columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],},
                                                                   customize: function (doc) { 
                                                                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 8; //2, 3, 4, etc 
                                                                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 8; //2, 3, 4, etc 
                                                                    doc.content[1].margin = [ -13, 0, 13,  0] //left, top, right, bottom
                                                                    },
                                                                 }],
                                                                 
                                                                 
            ajax: {

                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    Pre_Calculated_Group: $(this).find('select[name="Pre_Calculated_Group[]"]').val(),
                    Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_From: $(this).find(
                        'input[name="Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_From"]').val(),
                    Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_To: $(this).find(
                            'input[name="Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_To"]')
                        .val(),
                },
                
               
               /* complete : function (data) { // if uncomment this the alert will show but no data display in table
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                },*/
               success: function (reponse, textStatus, data){ //data respond here same as complete function 
                    /*console.log(reponse);
                    console.log(textStatus);*/
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#alert").hide();
                    $("#alert").slideDown("slow");
                    $("#alert").addClass("success");
                    $("#alert").find("div").text("Completed");
                    $("#alert").find("ol.ui.list").remove();
                    $("#alert").find("p").text("Done");
                    $("#submit").removeClass("double loading");             
                    //return data;

                },
               
                error: function (error) {
                   
                    $("#tableLabel").hide();
                    $("#alert").slideDown("slow");
                    $("#alert").removeClass("success");
                    $("#alert").addClass("error");
                    $("#alert").find("div").text("Failed");
                    $("#alert").find("ol.ui.list li").remove();
                    $("#submit").removeClass("double loading");
                   $.each(error.responseJSON[0], function (key, value) {
                      // console.log(value);
                       //console.log(key);
                       $("#alert").find("ol.ui.list").append("<li value='•'>" + value + "</li>");
                       switch(key) { // To display red error in each field
                          case "Pre_Calculated_Group":
                            $("#Pre_Calculated_Group").addClass("error");
                            $('body').toast({title: 'Fail',
                                        class: 'error',
                                        displayTime: 5000,
                                        showProgress: 'bottom',
                                        message: value});
                                       
                            break;
                          case "Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_From":
                            $("#Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_From").addClass("error");
                            $('body').toast({title: 'Fail',
                                        class: 'error',
                                        displayTime: 5000,
                                        showProgress: 'bottom',
                                        message: value});
                            break;
                          case "Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_To":
                            $("#Pre_Calculated_Group_Date_To").addClass("error");
                            $('body').toast({title: 'Fail',
                                        class: 'error',
                                        displayTime: 5000,
                                        showProgress: 'bottom',
                                        message: value});

                          break;  
                        }
  
                   });
                   
                }
                       
            },
            columns: [{"data": "****"}, // Sorry cannot show columns name
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      {"data": "****"},
                      ],
            deferRender: true, // To speed up the condition in case more than 50K row
            select: {style: 'multi'},
                     
        });
```

#### Response preview from success function (Does not show in table)

[image]

#### Response preview from complete function (shown in table)

[image]

Both have the same data.

#### Console log print the data in the success function

[image]

#### Console log print the data in the complete function

[image]

Also, both are the same.

#### Controller

I use a data table from [yajrabox](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) and return [collection](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-collection#dependency-injection) via Facade

```
//...

 if (!empty($finalData)) {
          // dd($finalData);
            $result = new Collection;

            foreach($finalData as $k => $v){
              //--- some logic
            ]);
           
            
             return DataTables::collection($result)->toJson();
           
        } else {
            return back()->withErrors($result)->withInput($request->all())->with('Fail', 'No Data Between This Date Range.');
        }
```

Using laravel 8.

**Is there any way to sue both success and complete with getting data in a table?**

### Any help, please

**Thanks for all.**

Comment: When using the DataTables `ajax` option, you should not use the `success` function. See [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) which makes the point: _"the success option of ajax should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete"_. Use the `ajax.dataSrc` option instead.

Comment: **Thanks a lot bro**, it is work I just change `success function` to be like `dataSrc: function (json){
                   // console.log(reponse);
                    //console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(json.data);          
                    return json.data ;

                },` and I removed `complete function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the DataTables `ajax` option, you should not use the `success` function.

See [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) which makes the point:

> "*the success option of ajax should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete*".

Use the `ajax.dataSrc` option instead.